# Передать массив в php из Smarty 2

Tags: php, smarty

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть сайт на шаблонизаторе Smarty 2
В шаблоне задействую пользовательскую функцию php def_desc($cat,$reg), которая подключается при открытии страницы.
В Smarty вызываю функцию:

`{%assign var='description' value=$category|def_descr:$region%}`

где $category и $region - ассоциативные массивы
Но при проверке в пользовательской функции $category передается как значение, но не массив.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вы проверьте на всякий случай, что перед вызовом этого кода category и правда является массивом

Comment: Если бы не проверил не написал бы.

Comment: попробуйте в скобки завернуть `value=(....)`

Comment: Этот фокус не прокатывает в Smarty. Скобки там работают как ковычки, т.е. передается строка, которая пишется после value=. Такое ощущение, что передается не массив, а последний элемент в массиве.

Comment: как там все во 2й версии сложно. Обратные кавычки написано в документации надо использовать для выражений.

Comment: Да, только для арифметических. Просто есть проект, разработчик платформы вроде развивает, но кодирует и закрывает основные модули, которые у него через жопу сделаны типа сео, а переходить на 3 версию не хочет. Вот и приходится херней заниматься.

Answer (score 0):

Долбанный Smarty 2!
В первом параметре до вертикальной черты Smarty 2 не хочет брать массивы!
Зато второй и далее пожалуйста.
Вопрос решен.